# Does Recharts have an option for floating bar charts?

Tags: boxplot, floating, recharts

I want to create a floating bar chart that mimics a boxplot, since Recharts doesn't have a boxplot option. Is there a way to create a floating box plot in Recharts?

Answer (score 0):

#### Floating Bar chart

Yes!

Setting the data to be an array of two values will work.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    uv: [1500, 4500]
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    uv: [1000, 3000]
  },
];
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-bar-chart-forked-ol9h5

Update:
To get it to be floating if the `Bar` has a `stackId`
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#stackId, have one stack be at the bottom with color: transparent